# upload file, convert csv to html

Tags: javascript, php, html, csv

**Upload file from local area.** 
Convert *csv file to html*. 
How is this done with php?

```
$data = file("sample.csv"); //local area file upload ?
foreach ($data as $line) {
    $lineArray = explode(";", $line);
    list($col1, $col2, $col3, $col4) = $lineArray;
    print $col1,$col2,$col3,$col4,;
}
```

Comment: can show you csv content, like what do you want to be html

Comment: I do not want to use fopen. how does it work by selecting a local file?

Comment: how is it done with form post method?

Answer (score 0):

You can ty this code

```
<?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$f = fopen("sample.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
```

Comment: I do not want to use fopen. how does it work by selecting a local file?

Comment: you can write your own function, which after each element of the array puts a comma and converts it all into strings. but why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: sample.csv; 

col1, col2, col3, col4,

print <tr><td>$col1</td><td><a href="$col3">"$col2</a></td><img src="$col4" /></tr>

Comment: use function [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). get an array and print it with html tags

Comment: `fgetcsv(fopen("sample.csv", "r"));` function [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) read each line as array element

Comment: sorry. I want to convert it by selecting the file from the folder.